# Reading Service Fabric Project Configuration in other project dll

Tags: c#, .net, azure, microservices, azure-service-fabric

I have a stateful microservice which is using another dll to read configuration from the ApplicationManifest.xml present in service fabric application. I am able to read the config in the microservice itself using StatefulServiceContext class. But when I try to read the same in another project(shared library), I am unable to.

Has anybody tried/struggled with the same? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: If you don't provide the error details it is hard to understand what is the problem!

Comment: There is no error. I want to know a way how to read service-fabric config from another shared project in the same solution

Comment: The service context is only available at runtime, if you need to get the context information to have access to the settings, you should pass(inject) the context to the library using it, the rest should work the same way as you did from within the service. You also will need to add the reference to the SF packages in the Library project.